# How to create and access packages containing html polymer custom element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to follow the example at this link [enter link description here](https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/tree/master/web/custom_elements_from_package_import)

My library structure is such:

```
epimss-polymer
  -lib
    -src
       -registration
         -personnel
            +credentials-form.html
```

I have tried many variations of

```
   <link rel="import" href="packages/epimss-polymer/registration/personnel/credentials-form.html">
```

but none works.

What is the correct way to access these .html files? For .dart files, my application works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `-` for package names.

You forgot the `src` directory.
Only the `lib` part can be omitted.

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/epimss_polymer/registration/src/personnel/credentials-form.html">
```

(I changed the `-` to `_`)

I guess nobody saw you question earlier because you haven't added the `dart` tag.